# Type 'dep' not known in line 1 of ross-latest.list

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installod ROS Hydro and am trying to get it working.  None of the commands seem to work .  I started to reinstall ROS and when I got to sudo apt-get update (to get the latest Debian stuff)I get this message E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ross-latest.list
followed by: E: The list of sources could not be read.
I did not get these messages on the initial install (or didn't see them).
How do I fix this?  It seems to be what's keeping ROS from working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114486/type-%27dep%27-not-known-in-line-1-of-ross-latest.list/) by [DelWilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4605/delwilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DelWilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4605/delwilson/) on 2014-01-02**:
Clarification: one file is named ros-latest.list and starts with dep and the other ross-latest.list which starts with deb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dep is a typo; it should be deb

You should only have one ros-latest.list. I suggest you remove ross-latest.list and correct your existing ros-latest.list.

EDIT:

You should be able to make the above changes using sudo:

Remove the offending file: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ross-latest.list`

Edit the existing file: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`

It also sounds like you are using grep incorrectly. When given a single argument, grep reads from stdin (usually the terminal); this is probably what you're seeing. Try running grep like: `grep -r -i ros /etc/apt/` ; this will grep recursively (`-r`, all files and subfolders), ignoring case (`-i`) for anything matching `ros` in the directory `/etc/apt/`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DelWilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4605/delwilson/) on 2014-01-02**:
ahendrix,
Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately the files are read only and I can't remove them or I don't know how to.  I'm new to linux as well as ROS.  BTW the ros-latest.list has deb as the first paremeter and it's the file the system is giving errors on.

I also note that when I grep ROS the cursor (small rectangle) blinks for a few seconds and then stops blinking and the system seems hung; no response for tens of seconds.  That doesn't seem normal.  Given this is an old machine, Del 9300 laptop but I expected more than that.

I'm not convinced I have a clean Ubuntu load.
Reinstall completed, I now have a pure Ubuntu machine :-) ROS reinstalled everything seems to be working fine.  Thanks for the suggestions and the help in understanding a little more about Linux.